# How to recognize english letter and also non english letter?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, computer-science

So I want to build a system which can recognize english letter. The input will be a random handwriting image(grayscale image, no background). **The problem is that I want the system to react correctly if the input is an image that is not an english letter.** For example, if the input is an image of handwriting 'a', then the system should output 'a'. But if the input is a handwriting β, or even a hand drawing cat, the system should output "not an english letter". How can I acheive this? If I use CNN or other deep learning algorithm, then how can I choose data set that represents the class of "non english letter"?

Answer (score 0):

Great question!  You would train it on the MNIST dataset.  In addition, you would add another category, "not_english".  In this category you would insert images of the same shapes and sizes as the MNIST images, but they would be non-english letters or drawings of cats or whatever you want to do.

Alternatively, you could, again, train on the MNIST dataset, and set a confidence threshold.  If the machine is less than 50% confident that the image you put in is an English character, you can program it to output "non english letter".